# My arm isn't following the cursor properly in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´m creating a 2D platformer in Unity and I have a problem when my player rotates the arm towards the mouse. I've programmed it so that the arm rotates towards the cursor, and when my character is facing right, it works fine, but when it´s facing left, the it doesn't.

So, when facing right, the arm follows the cursor, and when the cursor is behind the player, the arm flips and follows the cursor until the cursor is facing the front of the player again. Pretty straight forward. But then, when I want to face the player to the left, I obviously press the 'D' key and now walk to the left, and the arm rotation works when the cursor is facing the front of the player, just like before, bt the problem happens when I put the cursor behind the player, and the arm, instead of turning around, just keeps facing forward and I can still control it, but it just doesn't face backwards.

That's about as clear as I can put it, and thank you for reading it.

Here's the code and I'll see if I can put a video or a photo attachment.
This code is the script to rotate the arm.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pivot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject myPlayer;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;

        difference.Normalize();

        float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotationZ);

        if (rotationZ < -90 || rotationZ > 90)
        {
            if (myPlayer.transform.eulerAngles.y == 0)
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, rotationZ );
            }
            else if (myPlayer.transform.eulerAngles.y != 0)
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(180, 180, rotationZ - 50);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you can help me out I would really appreciate it! And tell me if I should add more information.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for responding late, but it just stops moving when you get past 90 degrees, and under -90 degrees?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15667460/ken

Comment: yes i think so.